# Outlook rule action "move to folder" stops processing other rules?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I'm trying to apply some actions first, then other actions with the following rules. So, somewhat like pipeline of rules in order not to repeat the same steps for each rule. Trivial example: 
rule 1: assign category, move to another folder
rule 2: mark as read when categoty="green"

So, rule 2 will never work since move to another category, apparently stops processing other rules.

It's a restriction? Any workarounds?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: done. now better?

Comment: Have you tried to put those options in the same rule? Also, have you checked to make sure the "stop processing more rules" option is not selected?

Comment: I don't want to make all the operations in each rule because I don't want to repeat it. And I don't use "stop processing more rules", as I mentioned )